# Why are people exporting and then importing every single function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to find where / understand why people are exporting every single function individually in javascript files?

https://github.com/chriso/validator.js/blob/master/src/index.js

```
const version = '5.4.0';

import toDate from './lib/toDate';
import toFloat from './lib/toFloat';
import toInt from './lib/toInt';
import toBoolean from './lib/toBoolean';
import equals from './lib/equals';
import contains from './lib/contains';
import matches from './lib/matches';

import isEmail from './lib/isEmail';
import isURL from './lib/isURL';
import isMACAddress from './lib/isMACAddress';
import isIP from './lib/isIP';
import isFQDN from './lib/isFQDN';

import isBoolean from './lib/isBoolean';

import isAlpha from './lib/isAlpha';
import isAlphanumeric from './lib/isAlphanumeric';
import isNumeric from './lib/isNumeric';
import isLowercase from './lib/isLowercase';
import isUppercase from './lib/isUppercase';

import isAscii from './lib/isAscii';
import isFullWidth from './lib/isFullWidth';
import isHalfWidth from './lib/isHalfWidth';
import isVariableWidth from './lib/isVariableWidth';
import isMultibyte from './lib/isMultibyte';
import isSurrogatePair from './lib/isSurrogatePair';

import isInt from './lib/isInt';
import isFloat from './lib/isFloat';
import isDecimal from './lib/isDecimal';
import isHexadecimal from './lib/isHexadecimal';
import isDivisibleBy from './lib/isDivisibleBy';

import isHexColor from './lib/isHexColor';

import isJSON from './lib/isJSON';
import isNull from './lib/isNull';

import isLength from './lib/isLength';
import isByteLength from './lib/isByteLength';

import isUUID from './lib/isUUID';
import isMongoId from './lib/isMongoId';

import isDate from './lib/isDate';
import isAfter from './lib/isAfter';
import isBefore from './lib/isBefore';

import isIn from './lib/isIn';

import isCreditCard from './lib/isCreditCard';

import isISIN from './lib/isISIN';
import isISBN from './lib/isISBN';

import isMobilePhone from './lib/isMobilePhone';

import isCurrency from './lib/isCurrency';

import isISO8601 from './lib/isISO8601';

import isBase64 from './lib/isBase64';
import isDataURI from './lib/isDataURI';

import ltrim from './lib/ltrim';
import rtrim from './lib/rtrim';
import trim from './lib/trim';
import escape from './lib/escape';
import unescape from './lib/unescape';
import stripLow from './lib/stripLow';
import whitelist from './lib/whitelist';
import blacklist from './lib/blacklist';
import isWhitelisted from './lib/isWhitelisted';

import normalizeEmail from './lib/normalizeEmail';

import toString from './lib/util/toString';

const validator = {
  version,
  toDate,
  toFloat, toInt,
  toBoolean,
  equals, contains, matches,
  isEmail, isURL, isMACAddress, isIP, isFQDN,
  isBoolean,
  isAlpha, isAlphanumeric, isNumeric, isLowercase, isUppercase,
  isAscii, isFullWidth, isHalfWidth, isVariableWidth,
  isMultibyte, isSurrogatePair,
  isInt, isFloat, isDecimal, isHexadecimal, isDivisibleBy,
  isHexColor,
  isJSON,
  isNull,
  isLength, isByteLength,
  isUUID, isMongoId,
  isDate, isAfter, isBefore,
  isIn,
  isCreditCard,
  isISIN, isISBN,
  isMobilePhone,
  isCurrency,
  isISO8601,
  isBase64, isDataURI,
  ltrim, rtrim, trim,
  escape, unescape, stripLow,
  whitelist, blacklist,
  isWhitelisted,
  normalizeEmail,
  toString,
};

export default validator;
```

https://github.com/chriso/validator.js/blob/master/src/lib/isBoolean.js

```
import assertString from './util/assertString';

export default function isBoolean(str) {
  assertString(str);
  return (['true', 'false', '1', '0'].indexOf(str) >= 0);
}
```

Is this considered more maintainable? Or what is this purpose?

Comment: I would probably group at least a couple of those into the same file; having dozens of tiny files seems a bit maddening. OTOH, at least that's a straight forward rule to follow rather than the more subjective decisions which go into grouping "similar" functions. Which is "better" is very debatable and depends on your definition of and goals for "better".

Comment: Also note that it's not "people" who do this, but rather "one random guy on the internet". And `import` is an ES6 thing not yet implemented in any major browser, so just about any older project uses a different (and in my experience, less verbose) form of importing (e.g. `require`'ing modules instead of individual functions).

Comment: If the logic is to have 1 function per 1 file, then it becomes trivial to browse and maintain source code. Using ES6 / HTTP2 or bundling tools such as `jspm bundle` / `webpack`, it becomes irrelevant how many files there are, it's simply much easier (logically) to maintain a project if one function is defined by one file.  Having dozens of tiny files isn't maddening as long as the structure and logic of separation is being respected. It's also easy to create tests for such a project. Bear in mind that many still live in the cabbage jquery world and don't know anything about ES specs.